# PHP unable to load dynamic library "php_pdo_oci.dll"

Tags: php, dynamic-library

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 with PHP 5.5.9 on Windows 8. I installed PHPUnit and this warning image "warning" started to pop up.

[image]

Yes I enabled extension loading in php.ini as well as "extension_dir" to correct folder and there is file named "php_pdo_oci.dll" in that folder.
I tried to use different apache and php releases, but it didn't help. 
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: what if you pass the whole, absolute path to the dll, just for testing?

Comment: Seems you're running XAMPP, instead of standalone Apache & PHP. Do you misunderstand something?

Comment: @Raptor For now i'm running xampp, because it didn't work with standalone apache and php. I also tried wamp..

Comment: @hek2mgl it won't work. php.ini extension_dir must be directory.

Comment: Does your Errorlog contain some more info? There could be an error with another part of the extension. Please see C:\xampp\apache\logs for the files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ..._oci.dll is part of the Oracle C Interface. Unless you need to use Oracle, I suggest you go to the relevant line inside the php.ini file and uncomment the loading of this extension. However, if you need to use this extension, you’ll need to install the free Oracle Client libraries and add them to the path.

Oracle has a page where you can download the libraries needed for your setup work as expected and you can see here:
[Oracle Instant Client Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html)

Note: After you choose your operational system (Windows as in your answer) in download section you will see the installation guide in foot notes of the next page. For others OSs this process will work the same way.

Comment: I tried your answer with WAMP Server v3.1.7 64bit on Windows 10 64bit with PHP 7.2.14, Apache 2.4.37. Be sure to have the correct path in your PATH environment variable... that is the path with all the files (jar/dll/sym/dll etc...). In my first attempt I extracted the Oracle client archive to c:\oracle folder and used that in my PATH, but I overlooked that the archive also contained a folder instantclient_12_2. So for me the correct folder was to use `C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2`. Also since I already had a working WAMP installation I could skip all the redistributable installations.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have PHP version 7.1.9 and encountered this problem and resolved the issue. Just ensure these lines in your php.ini file are uncommented like so:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
```

Please restart your server application (IIS, Apache e.t.c.) after any changes to your php.ini file.

Answer (score -1):

Please add below line in php.ini file

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
```

and restart apache server and check.