# php_pdo_oci.dll is not found on PHP 7 although commented on PHP.ini

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, codeigniter, dll

I have error on my codeigniter application on upgrading from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0 . 
My codeigniter is using MYSQL database and IIS web server.
I noted that `php_pdo_oci.dll` extension has deprecated on PHP 7.0 .

I learn that this extension is for Oracle.
Since the app does not even use Oracle , why is this extension library required to be loaded? Has Anyone ever experienced this? How do we turn off the file load, `php_pdo_oci.dll` ?

Thanks.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files
>   \php70\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of `Oracle C Interface` you can disable the extension in your `php.ini` by commenting that line will do the trick or if you want to install that extension try [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html)

refer : [PHP unable to load dynamic library "php_pdo_oci.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604780/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-pdo-oci-dll)

Comment: hello Arun . I have commmented the line to load this extension ,but it still loads the extension strangely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem first go to you php.ini and comment out the pdo_oci
and after that open xampp and you will find 4 options in the xampp horizontal to apache start/stop admin config go to config and php.ini and comment the php_pdo_oci there also and you are done

Comment: This answer is a little hard to read, can you please reorganize the instructions into an ordered list?